# Display event log data from different days on a 0 to 24 hour timeline

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, event-log

I have the following dataframe with a bunch of entries for errors that occured at specific times and dates:

```
| id | time_at_error           | error_time   | error_date   |
|----|-------------------------|--------------|--------------|
|0   | 2022-03-30 12:20:35.313 | 12:20:35.313 | 2022-03-30   |
|........................................................
```

My goal is to make a timeline plot that shows `error_date` on the y axis and on the x axis there should be drawn one point for each occurence of an event. The x axis should only go from 00:00 to 24:00 so one is able to visually see patterns in the event occurences.

At the moment I'm currently stuck with this:

[image]

**Question**: How can I set the x axis that it only goes from 00:00 to 24:00?

My code so far:

```
# Creating a set for all the dates in the df
dateSet = set(dfSequence.error_date)
dateSet = sorted(list(dateSet))

x = []
y = []

for i,r in dfSequence.iterrows():
    x.append(r["error_time"].strftime('%H:%M'))
    y.append(r["error_date"].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.ylim((-1,len(dateSet)))
plt.yticks(range(len(dateSet)), dateSet)

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching and trying out different approaches I came up with a solution. Maybe not the most beautiful but it does the job.

I simply took the `error_time` column and converted it to a datetime-object which makes all the hours get the same date. With that you can display all of the hours correctly.

The code:

```
dfSequence["error_time"] = dfSequence["time_at_error"].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
dfSequence["error_date"] = dfSequence["time_at_error"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Creating a set for all the dates in the df
dateSet = set(dfSequence.error_date)
dateSet = sorted(list(dateSet))

x = []
y = []

for i,r in dfSequence.iterrows():
    x.append(r["error_time"])
    y.append(r["error_date"])

dates = pd.to_datetime(x)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.ylim((-1,len(dateSet)))
plt.xlim(pd.to_datetime("00:00:00"), pd.to_datetime("23:59:59"))
plt.yticks(range(len(dateSet)), dateSet)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.scatter(dates,y)
plt.show()
```

- `dates` turns all the hours in a datetime-object
- `plt.xlim(pd.to_datetime("00:00:00"), pd.to_datetime("23:59:59"))` creates a range from 00:00 to 23:59 for the x axis
- `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())` creates tick labels for every hour

The result:

[image]